# Cast Integer type to float in BigQuery Standard Sql

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery Legacy Sql, we can cast Integer column to float type using float() function.

What is its equivalent in BigQuery Standard Sql? 
I have tried these commands:

I have tried these commands:

SELECT float( author.time_sec )  FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` LIMIT 1000

SELECT cast( author.time_sec as float)  FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` LIMIT 1000

Both of them failed.

Comment: what have you tried so far? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#casting

Comment: I have tried these commands:

SELECT float( author.time_sec )  FROM ``bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`` LIMIT 1000

SELECT cast( author.time_sec as float)  FROM ``bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`` LIMIT 1000

Both of them falied

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Standard SQL supports the `CAST` function with the [`FLOAT64` data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types), e.g.:

```
SELECT CAST(author.time_sec as FLOAT64)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you for your questions, by the way! Other users who are trying out standard SQL may be looking for similar information, so the questions and answers will help them too.